# Replace & char in php

Tags: php

I want replace google&stack to google and stack. please guide me

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: i want google&stack to google and stack

Comment: `str_replace('google&stack', 'google and stack', $str)` - Where's the problem?

Comment: did you even google this question before asking it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$str =  str_replace('google&stack', 'google and stack', $str);
```

or

```
$str =  str_replace('&', ' and ', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$string = "google & stack";
$string = str_replace(" & "," and ",$string);
$string = str_replace("&"," and ",$string);
```

Returns google & stack

And it also works when `$string = google&stack"`

### Edit(since you changed the question):

```
$string = "google&stack";
str_replace("google&stack","google and stack",$string)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
echo str_replace("&","and","facebook&google");
```

Comment: with google & facebook string it work googd. but google&facebook it not work